# Issue Passing JS variable to PHP include file

Tags: php, javascript, html, include

I have a php file where I am using it to setup dynamically generated pages based on the input variables. It starts on and index.html page where the variables are gathered some of which are not simple strings but complex Google Earth objects. On the submit of that page it is posted to another page and you are redirected to the created file. The trouble is coming when I try to use that variable within the php include file that is used to generate the pages.How do i properly get a variable from this form and then pass it through to be able to use it on the new generated page. Here is what I am trying currently.

On the click of this button the variable flyto1view is set.

```
 $("#flyto1").click(function(){          
    if (!flyto1view){
        flyto1view = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
            $("#flyto1view1").val(flyto1view)
    }
    else {
        ge.getView().setAbstractView(flyto1view);

    }
});
```

Then from here I have tried setting the value to an **hidden** field but Im not sure if that kinda of variable has a value that can be set like that. Whats the best way to get this variable to here after post

```
<? 
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Submit" && !empty($_POST['address']))     {//if submit button clicked and name field is not empty 
$flyto1view1 = $_POST['flyto1']; 
$address = $_POST['address']; //the entered name 
$l = $address{0}; // the first letter of the name 

// Create the subdirectory: 
// this creates the subdirectory, $l, if it does not already exists 
// Note: this subdirectory is created in current directory that this php file is in. 
if(!file_exists($l))  
{  
mkdir($l);  
} 
// End create directory 

// Create the file: 
$fileName = dirname(__FILE__)."/$address.html"; // names the file $name 
$fh = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
// The html code: 
// this will outpout: My name is (address) ! 
$str = "    
<?  php include ('template.php') ?>

"; 
fwrite($fh, $str); 
fclose($fh); 
// End create file 

echo "Congradualations!<br /> 
The file has been created. 
Go to it by clicking <a href=\"$address.html\">here</a>."; 
die(); 
 } 

// The form: 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly. creating files from user input is pretty risky.  Maybe this is only an abstract of your code but doing a `mkdir` from the first letter of the input without checking that the first letter is actually a letter and not a dot, slash, or other character isn't good practice.

Anyway, on to your question. I would probably use $_GET variables to pass to the second file.  So in the second file you use `<?php $_GET['foo'] ?>` and on the first file you do:

```
echo "Congradualations!<br /> 
    The file has been created. 
    Go to it by clicking <a href=\"$address.html?foo=$flyto1view1\">here</a>.";
```

You could also echo the variable into your template like so:

```
$str = '
    <?php 
        $var = \'' . $flyto1view1 . '\';
        include (\'template.php\')
    ?>';
```

Comment: Agreed with the riskiness but I will be the only one using this page to create "templated" documents. If I was to do it as shown could i just use the variable in the url?

Comment: Yeah you could use the variable in the url. I will edit my comment to reflect that.

Comment: I've also updated my comment to show how to directly add the var into the template.

Comment: okay one last question. is this method using the hidden field? is there any way to just grab or post the variable without using the hidden field?

Comment: I'm not sure which hidden field you are talking about. Could you post your HTML?

Comment: edited my original post I had mistakenly typed "empty" instead of "hidden". id prefer to not use a hidden field at all if the variable can just be pullled from the JS variable and doesnt need to be put into a hidden input field. Im a semi-noob all self taught so i have some knowledge gaps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26831/discussion-between-go3dexpansion-and-chrislondon)